# Are there short keys for switching tabs in chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

Are there short keys for switching tabs in chrome browser, for example:
switch to the next tab according to their order in chrome browser window
switch to a previous visited tab
switch to a tab, which you want.

My Chrome browser is Chromium 33.0.1750.152 Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about Web browser functionality belong on [su].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to the next tab, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to the previous tab.

Chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>#number</kbd> to go directly to tabs 1 to 9.

Answer (score 2):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd> to switch between tabs, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> to close the tabs I don't need anymore and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>#</kbd> (1 to 9) to navigate straight to a desired tab, although many times I have 15 to 20 tabs opened at the same time so this last set of keys isn't a reflex gesture yet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget Ctrl - W closes a tab, sure.
 but what if you closed the wrong tab? Ctrl - Shift - T open's it back up!